# FOR loops in MATLAB and numerical error

Tags: matlab

I have a loop that sums the values of function called pdfomegat

```
omegat= -1.9999:0.01:+1.9999;
sum1=0;

for j=1:length(omegat)

   func(j)=pdfomegat(j)*0.01;
   sum1=sum1+func(j);
end

    c1=sum1;
```

My second loop is slightly different loop and is as follows

```
sum2=0;
syms t 
for j=1:length(omegat)

   func2(j)=t*pdfomegat(j)*0.01;
   sum2=sum2+func(j);
end

    c2=sum2;
```

I know for fact that c1 is 1 .. However notice that in the second loop I change nothing but multiply by symbolic character t. Howver I get that

c2=0.99999464659732599597363744692302*t.

Why isn't c2=t?

Is there any ways I can fix it, I can't use the round function because it symbolic.. Any thoughts?

Comment: Am I supposed to read the document to know the answer :)? I am guessing there is nothing wrong with the code. Its just something to with MATLAB itself? @Nitish

Comment: Matlab uses a floating point representation for non-integers. Unfortunately, they do not have infinite precision. There are techniques for limiting the error (e.g. sum numbers from smallest to largest) but ultimately the only way around it is to only use integers.

Comment: is there any way I can fix it? @AndrewPiliser My problem requires alot of precision :(

Comment: @George Why do you need that much precision? Your example has only 0.0005% error.

Comment: I use the answer of this loop and integrate it. My function diverges if there is no precision belive it or not this error prevents matlab from computing the integral. If I replace 0.999 by 1 the integral converges.@AndrewPiliser

Answer (score 0):

After your loop call the double() function on your symbolic number to convert it to a regular number and then call the round function.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean double(c2)? If I do that I get an error Error in MuPAD command: DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array.

Comment: I dont think you can use either double or vpa because I have a symbolic expression.

Comment: You can extract the coefficients using [`coeffs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/coeffs.html) and then round them.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do that and used it but it gave me Error in MuPAD command: Expression is not a polynomial. @AndrewPiliser.. not sure why though Ihave defined t to be symbolic